# Find combination which does not have 'AC' status

Tags: sql-server

Consider the data below which is stored in temp table. How to get all those ID / State / Group combination which does not have Status record having 'AC' value ?

[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KStAh.png)

The result should yield

```
   ID  State  Group
    2   FL     LI
    3   FL     VA
    5   FL     LI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several query patterns that will achieve that result.

An example of one of those patterns, using an `GROUP BY` operation, with aggregation of a condition (to exclude the groupings where there's a row in the grouping that has a `status` value of `'AC'`)

```
  SELECT t.id
       , t.state
       , t.group
    FROM mytable t
   GROUP
      BY t.id
       , t.state
       , t.group
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN t.status='AC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

An example of another pattern, using an anti-join:

```
  SELECT t.id
       , t.state
       , t.group
    FROM mytable t
    LEFT
    JOIN mytable s
      ON s.id    = t.id
     AND s.state = t.state
     AND s.group = t.group
     AND s.status = 'AC'
   WHERE s.id IS NULL
   GROUP
      BY t.id
       , t.state
       , t.group
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a ton. My issue is resolved very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
FROM TableName t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableName 
                  WHERE [State] = t.[State]
                   AND [Group]  = t.[Group] 
                   AND [Status] = 'AC')
```